# IE 9 doesn't show dropdown on single click

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

I have the simple "select" control with several options. For some reason dropdown list is shown only on double click in IE 9 (IE 7, 8 works great - single click). There are no event handlers attached.

**UPDATED**

```
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="456">456</option>
</select>
```

I'm wondering about some solution/workaround.

Thanks

Comment: If you want help, post some code or link to a jsfiddle showing the problem.

Comment: So... First I have to guess your HTML and Javascript... Then I need to analyse my guess... and then I'm supposed to give you a correct answer... Sounds fair...

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2009/02/bug-487-onclickonfocus-bugs-on-select.html

It's a bug in all versions of ie.

Answer (score 0):

in IE you have to click click twice to update your selection if you use a style or a class with a applied width. It is a one click if you don't use width CSS on a SELECT tag.
This is my experience. Hope this helps a little...